# Create instance of class kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I create an instance of InfoA that contains also ***title***. Do I need to modify the classes?

Can't specify the title.

Also, do I need to create setters for it? To not access with the _

```
val info = InfoA(_subtitle = "SUBTITLE", title = ...)
```

```
  open class Info(
     open val action: Action = Action(),
     open val title: String? = ""
  ) {
    fun hasAction(): Boolean = action.hasAction()
  }

  class InfoA(
    private val _subtitle: String? = "",
    private val _image: String? = "",
    private val _backgroundImage: String? = "",
    private val _backgroundColor: String? = null,
    private val _foregroundColor: String? = null,
    private val _borderColor: String? = null
  ) : Info() {

    val subtitle: String
      get() = _subtitle.orEmpty()

    val image: String
      get() = _image.orEmpty()

    val backgroundImage: String
      get() = _backgroundImage.orEmpty()

    val backgroundColor: Int?
      get() = if (_backgroundColor != null) convertRgbStringToColorInt(_backgroundColor) else null

    val foregroundColor: Int?
      get() = if (_foregroundColor != null) convertRgbStringToColorInt(_foregroundColor) else null

    val borderColor: Int?
      get() = if (_borderColor != null) convertRgbStringToColorInt(_borderColor) else null
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is written, `title` is a `val`, so it can't be changed from its initial value — which is empty string if (as in the case of `InfoA`) something calls its constructor without specifying another value.

If it were changed to be a `var`, then it could be changed later, e.g.:

```
val info = InfoA(_subtitle = "SUBTITLE").apply{ title = "..." }
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep it a `val`, then `InfoA` would need to be changed: the most obvious way would be to add a `title` parameter in *its* constructor, and pass that up to `Info`:

```
class InfoA(
    title: String? = "",
    // …other fields…
) : Info(title = title) {
```

Note that this way, `InfoA` can never use `Info`'s default value for title, so you may need to duplicate that default in `InfoA`'s constructor.

The need to duplicate superclass properties in a subclass constructor is awkward, but there's currently no good way around it.  (See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029272/kotlin-how-to-simplify-passing-parameters-to-base-class-constructor).)  If there are many parameters, you might consider bundling them together into a single data class, which could then be passed easily up to the superclass constructor — but of course users of the class would need to specify that.  (Some people think that having more than a few parameters is a code smell, and that bundling them together can often improve the design.)

Comment: @PraveenP. Thanks for accepting my answer.  (But please note that on this site it's usually better to wait for a day, to give people who are busy or in other time-zones a chance.  Impossible as it may seem, someone might theoretically be able to write an even better answer than mine :-)

Comment: Also, I realise I didn't address your point about setters: those would only be possible if you changed the `val`s to `var`s; but it looks like you wouldn't need to override _both_ getters and setters to get the behaviour you want.  Though you shouldn't be afraid of nullable values; Kotlin is well set up to handle them safely, so in a case like this I'd probably look at using only the ‘bare’ properties defined in the constructor, without providing non-nullable versions at all.